# Writing a program to test opening hands for a card game

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

The startup of the game goes as follows:

1. Shuffle your deck of 60 cards
2. Draw 7 cards as your opening hand

Basically, I want to create a program to test how often my opening hands contain certain cards.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function shuffle(array) {
        var currentIndex = array.length,
            temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {

            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
    }

    let deckarray = ["Grubbin", "Grubbin", "Grubbin", "Charjabug", "Vikavolt",
        "Vikavolt", "Vikavolt", "Tapu LeLe", "Tapu LeLe", "Tapu Bulu",
        "Tapu Bulu", "Tapu Bulu", "Octillery", "Remoraid", "Remoraid", "N", "N",
        "N", "N", "Skyla", "Skyla", "Skyla",
        "Guzma", "Guzma", "Guzma", "Brigette", "Brigette", "Brigette", "Kukui",
        "Kukui", "Ultra Ball", "Ultra Ball",
        "Ultra Ball", "Ultra Ball", "Heavy Ball", "Rare Candy", "Rare Candy", "Rare 
Candy", "Rare Candy",
        "Choice Band", "Choice Band", "Choice Band", "Choice Band", "Float Stone",
        "Float Stone", "Energy Recycler",
        "Energy Recycler", "Field Blower", "Field Blower", "Lightning", "Lightning",
        "Lightning", "Lightning",
        "Grass", "Grass", "Grass", "Grass", "Grass", "Grass", "Grass"
    ];

    $('#shuffle').click(function() {
        $('#deck').empty();
        shuffle(deckarray);
        var openingHand;
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            openingHand += deckarray[i] + "<br />";
        }
        $('#deck').append(openingHand);
    });

    var sevenhand = [];
    var brigettecount = 0;
    $('#stats').click(function() {
        shuffle(deckarray);
        sevenhand.length = 0;
        brigettecount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                sevenhand.push(deckarray[i]);
            }
            if (sevenhand.includes("Brigette")) {
                brigettecount += 1;
            }
            console.log(brigettecount);
        }

    });
});
```

Essentially, I want the click function for the #stats button to test 10,000 opening hands. Eventually I want it to be able to give a percentage of times I open with a specific combination of cards but for now, I am trying to get it to log how many times I start with a card called "Brigette" in my opening hand of 7.

The click event above that simply shuffles and "redraws" 7 cards when clicked (It has a weird undefined at the beginning of the array but that's another topic I guess).

My issue is that when I click my `#stats` button it just counts forever and no cards are added to the `sevenhand` array nor does the `brigettecount` go up. This happens even after I corrected the `10,000` to `10000` as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: What *specific* issue are you facing?  "Any help is appreciated" is far too broad.

Comment: `10, 000` is not a number that javascript understands.  Use `10000`

Comment: Also, you wrote `"Rare` `Candy"` on separate lines, but JavaScript doesn't allow breaking single-quoted `'` or double-quoted `"` strings into multiple lines. You don't want the string to have a “new line” character in it like `"Rare\nCandy"`, so you should instead make sure to write the string on one line, like `"Rare Candy"`.

Comment: If you want to emulate a real deck of cards, you should `.pop()` whatever is drawn out of deckArray. That being said you'd have to start a brand new deck every 5 hands. So that's 2000 new decks.

Comment: My issue is basically that it doesnt work lol. Like when I click my #stats button it just counts forever and no cards are added to the sevenhand array nor does the brigettecount go up. I've corrected the 10,000 to 10000 though. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-do-you-calculate-the-likelihood-of-drawing-certain-cards-in-your-opening-han)

Here's a quick Javascript implementation of the hypergeometric distribution mentioned above.

The parameters are deck size (60), number of cards in the initial draw (7), and the number of duplicates of the card you want to calculate the probability for (3 "Brigette" in your deck).

```js
function hyperGeo(deckSize, cardsDrawn, wanted) {
  // x is the probability of *not* drawing one of the wanted cards
  // 1 - x is the probability of drawing *at least one* of the wanted cards
  var x = 1;
  for (var i=0; i < cardsDrawn; i++) {
    x *= (deckSize - i - wanted) / (deckSize - i);
  }
  return 1 - x;
}

console.log(hyperGeo(60, 7, 3));
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!